# Copy entire drive in use per batches

Tags: terminal, file-transfer, compression, archiving, copy

I need to copy entire network drive (approx. 1TB) that is constantly in use to a remote location but in that remote location, no file can be larger than 1.3GB.
How can I achieve this?
I cannot first create an archive of the entire drive and then split it into 1.3GB parts because there is no free space available for this and I cannot connect or use any other storage device.
I would like it to somehow start putting all the files to an archive and at the some time start splitting it into the 1.3GB parts and transferring them to the remote location.

I would really appreciate if anyone could help with this!
Thank you!

UPDATE 1: I can reach the remote location via SSH or directly mount it via SMB.

Comment: you should say exactly HOW you upload stuff to "remote location", is it ssh? samba? https rest api? the answer depends on what protocol you use to upload.

Comment: i have voted to close this question as "needs additional details" - specifically it needs details on how you upload files to "remote location". add that information and i will retract my close-vote.

Comment: @hanshenrik I have added the necessary details, sorry for that.

Comment: "network drive that is constantly in use": if you cannot make an image at a **specific point in time**, the task is impossible. Whatever you copy, the data on the drive will have changed.  "No man ever steps in the same river twice, for it's not the same river and he's not the same man." https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/117526-no-man-ever-steps-in-the-same-river-twice-for

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Well, yes, but not all the files are being modified constantly. What I meant was that at any given time, someone maybe accessing the drive over the network and reading/writing. Also, _there's none so blind as those who don't want to see_.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik maybe a LOCK_EX approach is good enough in practice?

Comment: Is there a hard point in time after which people will be expected to access the new storage? The times I've done this I've used Robocopy and done multiple successive copies, each subsequent time only copying those files where the source file's created or modified date/time are later than that of the destination file.

Answer (score 0):

you haven't exactly said HOW you transfer the files to the "remote location", but assuming you transfer the files via ssh/sftp and you have tar+zstd+ssh+split (fairly standard unix utilities, if you're on Windows you can use Cygwin) you could do

```
tar cf source_folder | zstd | ssh user@storageserver 'cd target; split --numeric-suffix --bytes=1300M - archive.zstd'
```

and on the target server you'll get files archive.zstd00 archive.std01 archive.zstd02 archive.zstd03 ~ for 1.3GB chunks.

where they're transferred entirely in RAM until they reach the target server :) ... ofc this won't work if your "remote location" isn't reachable over ssh, unfortunately you said nothing about how you reach the "remote location", which is unfortuante, because the correct answer depends on it. this is the correct answer if you happen to upload over ssh/sftp.

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful. What if I needed the archive to be encrypted too, would that be possible?

Comment: @yssup openssl to the rescue, something like ```tar cf source_folder | zstd | openssl enc -aes-128-ctr -a | ssh (...)```